# Golang GORM ORM - Structs from 3rd party packages as models?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to build an app which uses a 3rd party package. That package has some structs I would like to persist in my database. I could not find any answer to my question which is :

is it possible to persist 3rd party structs without having to rebuild that struct in a wrapper that can be stored?

For example:
3rd party struct "Person { age, name }

I want that Person struct to be a Gorm Model without having to recreate that struct like
type struct PersonWrapper { age, name } and populate the wrappers from the 3rd party struct values.

Comment: You are going to have to tag them with GORM tags, so you need new structs. You can easily convert between your structs and the third party structs if they only differ in tags though. You can simply copy them.

Comment: You don't want a third party lib vendor to be in control of your database structure.  Recreate the struct so you can maintain the database structure independently of a lib

Comment: you could try to loop through the struct values and dynamically assign the "gorm: <struct-tag-here>" to each new struct value. Not sure how this would work but just trying to provide some general pseudo thought process